# android wireless game

Tags: android, wireless

hello I'm final year student n me going to create my final year project in android.
i have basic ideas in android but don't know about creating game n wireless communication..
and my project topic is : wireless (airplay) gaming in android.

i want to create some simple 2 player game (like tic tac,chess and simple car or bike race)

and finally what i want, 
i want like my games is installed in 2 different android device. and they can play 1 player in other device and the 2nd player in other device.

even i haven't basic knowledge for this two big thing (developing game and connect wirelessly)

can any one help me for this
i want resource for this things.
thanx in advance :)

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: i just done to learn basic syntax and funda in android

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using the bluetooth protocol theirs a great [bluetooth chat sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) in the android sdk,
But bluetooth means that the 2 machines should be in a 30 meter distance from each other.

usually multi-player games just uses a server in the middle that temporarily saves the information and push it to the corresponding machine.

so pick an architecture and do some research and we could help you if you'll give further details,
And there's lots of tutorials about communication between android and any server side language.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The game side of the work for your project should be very straight forward (in that you don't need great or fast graphics and your game is turn based). The standard android developers site has good introductions to android programming.

From a communications side you need to choose what sort of technology you want to use:

1. The internet/TCPIP/local wireless network as a mechanism: Here you should look at sockets and think about how you are going to establish who the two parties are that want to play together
2. Some PAN technology such as IR/blue tooth which require physical proximity: Investigate the android stacks supporting these as suggested by Joe above

Good luck

Comment: i ll do on local wireless(bluetooth) for communiation..
and i get some resources for bluetooth communication :)
now jet need to lear about develop normal games.. any idea about it ??